# Why my field in mongodb is now null?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I insert everytime in mongo db a field like `{text:data.text,userId:'5454234ddsc32fcsd23dsdfe3'}`.After i insert more fields like this one remains ok,and the rest of all are null.What should i do?I think mongo see this like a duplicate.I thinks i should allow duplicates.Here is my schema.

```
var ConversationsSchema=new Schema({
conversations:{type:Array,
    text:String,
    sender:String,
    to:String,
    userId:{type:String,select:true,unique:false}
}
})
```

Update query:

```
Conversations.update(({_id:data.conversationID},{$addToSet:{conversations:{text:data.textMessage,sender:data.sender,to:data.to,userId:data.userId}}}),function(err){
                //console.log('Cannot update your conversation')
                console.log(err);
            })
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're inserting an object, but the schema expects an Array

Comment: No! I make an update where i use $addToSet.I have an array of objects and i simply introduce an object in array

Comment: Not only is that statement true but if this was intended to be an "array of objects" then the approach is all wrong. It kind of looks like you are trying to expand an `ObjectId` reference into a "User" object. But if you wan an array of objects then you notate the schema differently to this

Comment: If i chage the userId everytime it works...i need to allow duplicates for userId but i don't know how..I've tried with unique:false but doens't working

Comment: Show your queries/updates

Comment: I've update question

Comment: I have no idea why this was removed from current documentation, but the "old documentation" on this is really quite helpful and explanatory: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html. Not to mention a top search engine result.

Comment: i have no problem ...inserts in db everytime ...but don't allow me to insert every time the same value of a  userId

Answer (score 1):

Update!
Schema must be:

```
var ConversationsSchema=new Schema({
conversations:{type:Array,
    text:String,
    sender:String,
    to:String,
    userId:{type:String,select:true,index:{unique:false}}
}})
```